# Using JS Object Based Multidimensional Arrays to Collect, Store, and View Data in a PDF Form

Tags: javascript, object, pdf, multidimensional-array

I have an interactive PDF form created in Acrobat that employs a multidimensional object to collect, store, and populate form fields used to view the data. The form serves as a password manager to view individual password records whereby I have recently completed the lookup record page view that works like a charm. The only issue I've run into thus far is my inability to delete a record selected in the lookup view in which event I initially thought I'd be able to use the JS array.splice() method to simply delete a line item in the object array that stores the data for the particular record I want to delete. Come to learn that the script used to create the object that stores the data still remains inside the form whereby literally nothing has changed. Upon further study, I am inclined to believe that the form is essentially serving as a window to view the information stored in the object and for whatever reason invoking a script using the JS slice() method has no effect whatsoever on the script that created the object to begin with. Hence, in order to make this work, it appears I need to be able to rewrite/replace the script minus the object property/s that hold the data for the record to be deleted. Sorry for the novel. Any comments or suggestions regarding this subject matter are most appreciated. Thank you ahead of time.

Created a script using the JS splice() method in a futile attempt to remove data from an object used to collect and store data inside an interactive PDF form.

Answer (score 0):

From Adobe's Docs:

> You can use the Document JavaScript dialog box to add, edit, or delete scripts in your current document.
> To open the dialog box, choose Tools > JavaScript > Document JavaScript.

Here https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/add-debug-javascript.html

I've never used Adobe Acrobat, but if you need to edit a script in a PDF, that's probably where to get at it.

If you post the script's code, someone might be able to help you. It's almost impossible to get an answer to any question without posting code.

Comment: I apologize as I believe I may not have been clear in my initial post in that I was looking for a script to accomplish this task as opposed to doing it manually using acrobat pro to add, edit, or delete a document level JS which is a no brainer. Sorry for the confusion but I was eventually able to create the script on my own. I also should have added that any script or method used in the PDF I am presently working on also has to be supported by Adobe Reader. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize regarding my initial post as I knew little to nothing at the time regarding how to create and use an object literal in which event I have since learned how to use an object literal along with its methods to add, delete, and edit key-value pairs of an object literal. I was then able to resolve all my issues in using an Acrobat PDF form as a front end along with a hidden text field using JSON to convert a JS data object for organizing and storing my form data as a string. The script to accomplish this task is as follows:

```
dsFld =getField("dataSrc");// call getField method used to obtain the 
stored JS object as a JSON string
oVendors = JSON.parse(dsFld.value);//Parse the JSON string to manipulate 
the JS data object
btnDel=getField("btn.del");
var oFld;// create var oFld for later use
var oPassData = oVendors[event.value];
if(oPassData){// script to populate PDF form fields
  //walk members to fill fields
for(var nNm in oPassData){
// skip fields that don't exist on form
  oFld = this.getField("inf." + nNm);
  if(oFld)
  oFld.value = oPassData[nNm];// script to populate associated form 
  fields
}
```

In looking back, I am sorry for any inconvenience posed by my initial post.